# Searching and returning for "*1*" in a string returns instances containing "*11*" as well in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to extract cells through a combination of index(match) and right(len)-find() functions from an array of data with text. In my formula, I am searching for instances of "* DS#1 *", excel returns those but also returns instances with "* DS#11 *". How do I get excel to return only DS#1?

I have attempted to use an if statement with no success, if(formula="* 11 *","",formula).

Below is a link to an example of the data. The first cell highlighted in yellow should not be returning that text, it should be "". The second cell highlighted in yellow is appropriate to return that data.
[example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNPqc.png)

=RIGHT(INDEX($V:$AC,MATCH("DS#1",$AC:$AC,0),1),LEN(INDEX($V:$AC,MATCH(FW$1,$AC:$AC,0),1))-FIND($AG2,INDEX($V:$AC,MATCH(FW$1,$AC:$AC,0),1))+1)

Comment: Please provide samples of your data, and expected output.

Comment: You might first want to SUBSTITUTE() in the target string , instances of wildcard characters with non-wildcard characters before doing the search.

Comment: Factoring a '~' in your search might also help - Have a look here: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2011-excel-find-and-replace-asterisk-question-mark.html

Comment: Count the “*1*” and then subtract the count of the “*11*”...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a formula you can adapt to your ranges which will return a list from the range `rngDS` that contain `findDS`.  I used named ranges, but you can adapt them to your own ranges.

Not sure if this is what you want since you chose to not post examples of your data or desired results.

The routine finds the `findDS` string and then checks to be sure that the following character is non-numeric.

```
C1: =IFERROR(INDEX(rngDS,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(NOT(ISNUMBER(-MID(rngDS,SEARCH(findDS,rngDS)+LEN(findDS),1))+ISERROR(MID(rngDS,SEARCH(findDS,rngDS)+LEN(findDS),1))))*ROW(rngDS),ROWS($1:1))),"")
```

*and fill down*

[image]

Comment: Dang, you had the same idea, though yours has `AGGREGATE` integrated and therefor able to return more :)

Comment: @JvdV So long as the `searchstrings` are definitively ended with a non-numeric character, we can use that technique.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld I provided an example of the data above. Just to narrow down what I am looking for. I appreciate your help with this and your example is definitely very close to what I am looking for.

Comment: @Program12345 Your example is confusing.  You have a long string in a single cell and you want to return a portion of that string, I guess corresponding to the value in the `DS#` column.  You've got a bunch of `DS#`'s that appear in the column, and in your string, but no return in the adjacent column.  You write you are looking for `DS#1` but you show you want to return `DS#11`. `DS#1` doesn't even appear in the long string.  Your question really needs a lot of clarification.

Comment: @ Ron Rosenfeld To clarify a few things: I removed all data except the two highlighted for the example purpose to show how DS#1 and DS#11 rows behave. I am looking for DS#1, there is no DS#1 in any long string in my range of data. (long strings are throughout that entire column - only showing one for example purpose). Since there is no DS#1, I expect nothing to return. But I have DS#11 returning which is the main issue. I hope that adds some clarity.

Comment: @Program12345  Apparently your desired results refer to lines from which you have removed the data. Not very helpful. I suggest you try to adapt my approach to what you really want, or read about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly. You can use made-up data that enables someone to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is my first post on this site, so I appreciate the reference so that I could ask my questions clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Here some example on how to find a value and check for the following char.

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=INDEX(A2:A6,MATCH(1,INDEX((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("DS#1",B2:B6)))*(NOT(ISNUMBER(MID(B2:B6,SEARCH(C2,B2:B6)+LEN(C2),1)*1))),0),0))
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be very difficult to come up a formula based solution especially when you need to first differentiate DS1, DS#1. DS#11, DS#11X etc. then look for the text string after each DS code, not to mention these confusing codes may (or may not) be positioned in random orders in the text string.

A better approach would be using **Power Query** which is available in **Excel 2010 and later versions**. My solution is using **Excel 2016**.

Presume you have the following two tables:

[image: Source]

You can use **From Table** function in the **Data** tab to add both tables to the **Power Query Editor**.

Once added, make a duplicate copy of Table 1. I have renamed the duplicate as `Table1 (2) - Number Ref`. Then you should have three un-edited queries:

[image: Queries List]

If your source data is a larger table containing some other information, you can google how to add a worksheet to the editor and how to remove unnecessary columns and remove duplicated values.

> Firstly, let's start working with **Table1**.

[image: Table1]

Here are the steps:

1. Use **Replace Values** function to remove all **`#`** from the text string, and then replace all **`DS`** with **`DS#`** in the text string, so all DS codes are in the format of **`DS#XXX`**. Eg. **DS8** will be changed to **DS#8**. This step may not be necessary if DS8 is a valid code as well as DS#8;
2. Use **Split Column** function to split the text strings by the word **`DS`**, and put each sub text string into a **new row**, then you should have the following:

[image: Split into rows]

3. Use **Split Column** function again to split the text strings **by 1 Character from the left** and you should have the following:

[image: Split by 1 character]

4. **Filter** the first column to show hash tag **`#`** only and then remove the first column, then you should have the following:

[image: Filtered]

5. use **Replace Values** function repeatedly to remove the following characters/symbols from the text strings: `(`, `)`, `HT`, `JH`, `SK`, `//`, and replace dash `-` with space  . I presume these are irrelevant in the comment but you can leave them if needed. Then you should have:

[image: Cleaned]

6. use **Split Column** function again to split the text string by **the first space on the left**, then you should have:

[image: Splited Again]

7. Then you can **Trim** and **Clean** the second column to further tidy up the comments, rename the columns as **DS#**, **Comments**, and **Number Ref** consecutively, and **change the format of the third column to Text**. Then you should have:

[image: Renamed]

8. The last step is to **add a custom column** called `Match ID` to combine the value from first and third column into one text string as shown below:

[image: Added Column]

> Secondly, let's work on **Table1 (2) - Number Ref**

Here are the steps:

1. **Remove the first column** so leave the `Number Ref` column as the single column;
2. **Transpose** the column, and **Promote the first row as header**. Then you should have:

[image: Number Ref]

The purpose of this query is to **transform all Number Reference into column headers**, then **append** this query with the next query (**Table2**) to achieve the desired result which I will explain in the next section.

> Lastly, let's work on the third query **Table2**.

Here are the steps:

1. **Append** this table with the **Number Ref** table from previous step;

[image: Append]

2. highlight the whole table and use **Replace Values** function to replace all **`null`** with number **`1`**. Then highlight the first column and use **Unpivot Other Columns** function to transform the table as below:

[image: Unpivot]

3. then **Remove the last column** (`Value`), and **add a new custom column** called `Match ID` to combine the **DS code** with the **Number Reference**. Then you should have:

[image: Added Match ID]

4. **Merge** the table with **Table1** using `Match ID` as shown below:

[image: Merge]

5. **Expand** the newly merged column `Table1` to show Comments;

[image: Expand]

6. Use **Split Column** function to **split the first column by Non-digit to digit**, change the format of the `digit column` to **whole number**, and then **sort** `Attribute` column and the `digit column` ascending consecutively, then you should have:

[image: Sorted]

7. Use **Split Column** function again to split the `Match ID` column by dash sign `-`, and **remove the first three columns**, rename the remaining three columns as **DS#**, **Number Ref** and **Comments consecutively**, then you should have:

[image: Final]

8. **Close & Load** this table to a new worksheet as desired, which may look like this:

[image: Loaded]

> **In conclusion**, It is entirely up to you how you would like to structure the table in Power Query. You can pre-filter the Number Reference in the editor and load only relevant results to a worksheet, you can load the full table to a worksheet and use **VLOOKUP** or **INDEX** to retrieve the data as desired, or you can load the third query to data model from where you can create pivot tables to play around.

Here are the codes behind the scene for reference only. **All steps are using built-in functions** of the editor without any advanced manual coding.

**Table1**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Comments", type text}}),
    #"Replaced Value8" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type","#","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Comments"}),
    #"Replaced Value9" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value8","DS","DS#",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Comments"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Replaced Value9", {{"Comments", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("DS", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Comments"),
    #"Split Column by Position" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "Comments", Splitter.SplitTextByPositions({0, 1}, false), {"Comments.1", "Comments.2"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Split Column by Position", each ([Comments.1] = "#")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Comments.1"}),
    #"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Removed Columns",")","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Comments.2"}),
    #"Replaced Value2" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value1","-"," ",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Comments.2"}),
    #"Replaced Value3" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value2","(","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Comments.2"}),
    #"Replaced Value4" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value3","HT","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Comments.2"}),
    #"Replaced Value5" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value4","JH","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Comments.2"}),
    #"Replaced Value6" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value5","SK","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Comments.2"}),
    #"Replaced Value7" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value6","//","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Comments.2"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Replaced Value7", "Comments.2", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Comments.2.1", "Comments.2.2"}),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"Comments.2.2", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Cleaned Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Trimmed Text",{{"Comments.2.2", Text.Clean, type text}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Cleaned Text",{{"Comments.2.1", "DS#"}, {"Comments.2.2", "Comments"}}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Number Ref", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Match ID", each "DS#"&[#"DS#"]&"-"&[Number Ref])
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

**Table1 (2) - Number Ref**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Comments", type text}, {"Number Ref", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Number Ref"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Other Columns",{{"Number Ref", type text}}),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Changed Type1"),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"388", type any}, {"1", type any}})
in
    #"Changed Type2"
```

**Table2**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"List", type text}}),
    #"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Changed Type", #"Table1 (2) - Number Ref"}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Appended Query",null,"1",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"List", "388", "1"}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Replaced Value", {"List"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Value"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Match ID", each [List]&"-"&[Attribute]),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom", {"Match ID"}, Table1, {"Match ID"}, "Table1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table1", {"Comments"}, {"Comments"}),
    #"Split Column by Character Transition" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Expanded Table1", "List", Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition((c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9"}, c), {"0".."9"}), {"List.1", "List.2"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Character Transition",{{"List.2", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type1",{{"Attribute", Order.Ascending}, {"List.2", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Match ID", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("-", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Match ID.1", "Match ID.2"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"List.1", type text}, {"Match ID.1", type text}, {"Match ID.2", type text}}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type2",{"Match ID.1", "Match ID.2", "Comments"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Other Columns",{{"Match ID.1", "DS#"}, {"Match ID.2", "Number Ref"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the creative answers from this post, I was able to take some of these ideas and form a solution. There are two parts to the solution I found. The first is to replace the strings that I am trying to filter out with a random text that doesn't appear in any instance in my data. Since I had a range of data I needed to replace (DS11 through DS19), I used a VBA function to avoid a large nested function.

Once I had the strings I am trying to filter out replaced, I added an If(Isnumber(search()) function to display "" when the replaced text is returned.

```
Function REPLACETEXTS(strInput As String, rngFind As Range, rngReplace As Range) As String

Dim strTemp As String
Dim strFind As String
Dim strReplace As String

Dim cellFind As Range

Dim lngColFind As Long
Dim lngRowFind As Long
Dim lngRowReplace As Long
Dim lngColReplace As Long

lngColFind = rngFind.Columns.Count
lngRowFind = rngFind.Rows.Count
lngColReplace = rngFind.Columns.Count
lngRowReplace = rngFind.Rows.Count

strTemp = strInput

If Not ((lngColFind = lngColReplace) And (lngRowFind = lngRowReplace)) Then
    REPLACETEXTS = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    Exit Function
End If

For Each cellFind In rngFind

    strFind = cellFind.Value
    strReplace = rngReplace(cellFind.Row - rngFind.Row + 1, cellFind.Column - rngFind.Column + 1).Value
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, strFind, strReplace)

Next cellFind

REPLACETEXTS = strTemp

End Function
```